# Как получить числа из строки и корректно отсортировать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, сортировка, list

Есть файл с числами через запятую, без пробелов. Необходимо считать его и вывести в консоль отсортированный список по возрастанию и убиванию.

Вот мои попытки:

```
import re

try:
    file_path = open(input('Введите путь к файлу: '))
except IOError:
    print('File not found')
file_value = file_path.read()
file_numbers = re.findall('\d+', file_value)
# print(file_numbers)
# print(type(file_numbers))
sorted(file_numbers, key=int)
print(file_numbers)
sorted(file_numbers, key=int, reverse=True)
print(file_numbers)
```

Собственно результат:

> ```
> ['6', '2', '3', '13', '5', '1', '7', '9', '18', '20', '16', '12', '15', '14', '10', '11', '17', '9', '19']
> ['6', '2', '3', '13', '5', '1', '7', '9', '18', '20', '16', '12', '15', '14', '10', '11', '17', '9', '19']
> ```

В чем ошибка и как поправить? :(

Так же были попытки сделать вот так:

```
try:
    file_path = open(input('Введите путь к файлу: '))
except IOError:
    print('File not found')
file_value = file_path.read()
# file_numbers = re.findall('\d+', file_value)
file_numbers = []
for i in file_value:
    try:
        num = int(i)
        file_numbers.append(num)
    except ValueError:
        continue
# print(file_numbers)
# print(type(file_numbers))
sorted(file_numbers, key=int)
print(file_numbers)
sorted(file_numbers, key=int, reverse=True)
print(file_numbers)
```

И на выходе получил вообще бред:

> ```
> [6, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 7, 9, 1, 8, 2, 0, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 7, 9, 1, 9]
> [6, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 7, 9, 1, 8, 2, 0, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 7, 9, 1, 9]
> ```

Comment: print(sorted(file_numbers, key=int)). По коду думаю будет ясно

Comment: Спасибо Дмитрий, Ваш вариант с print(sorted(file... помог! Я понял в чем была ошибка, я сортировал, а потом просто выводил переменную старую...:)))

Comment: Результат функции sorted() надо же чему-то присвоить!

Comment: Да я уже понял))) сортировал и опять старую переменную выводил))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> И на выходе получил вообще бред:

Ваш код `sorted(file_numbers, key=int)` правильно был написан, но [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) возвращает новый отсортированный список, не изменяя исходный, поэтому вам нужно было сделать так:

```
file_numbers = sorted(file_numbers, key=int)
```

Можно отсортировать "на месте", как вы и хотели, но для этого нужно будет использовать [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

```
file_numbers.sort(key=int)
```

Answer (score 2):

Прежде всего, после получения списка *строк*, превратите его в список *чисел*:

```
file_numbers = [int(number) for number in file_numbers]
```

Затем - чтобы максимально сохранить ваш код - используйте вместо *функции* [`sorted()`](http://pythonz.net/references/named/list.sort/) *метод списка* [`sort()`](http://pythonz.net/references/named/list.sort/) (для прямой сортировки списка *на месте*):

```
file_numbers.sort()
print(file_numbers)

file_numbers.sort(reverse=True)      # или - более ефективно - file_numbers.reverse()
print(file_numbers)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
> [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 9, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1]
> ```